# SSH tunnel using pexpect

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel, pexpect

I'm just wondering if anyone here has built a ssh tunnel using pexpect and default libraries only? Which can connect from a one remote server1(linux) to another server2 (linux) to a Cisco Device.

I do have a working script (implement class and methods using pexpect) which can jump and connect to server2 to Cisco device and execute a specific linux command like pwd, hostname etc. Now, When I tried using a different command like doing a snmpwalk from server2 to device then that's the time i faced the below issue.

Issue:

```
sending line: snmpwalk 10.1.1.1 snmpEngineTime
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gosnmp.py", line 606, in <module>
    c.send('snmpwalk 10.1.1.1 snmpEngineTime')
  File "gosnmp.py", line 386, in send
    self.ssh_tunnel.expect(['%'],60)
  File "/home/<>/atools/SSH_TUNNEL/pexpect.py", line 1311, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/home/<>/atools/SSH_TUNNEL/pexpect.py", line 1325, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/home/<>/atools/SSH_TUNNEL/pexpect.py", line 1409, in expect_loop
    raise TIMEOUT (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
<pexpect.spawn object at 0xf20590>
version: 2.3 ($Revision: 399 $)
command: /usr/local/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/local/bin/ssh', '<>@1.1.1.1']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile("%")
e
e
after: <class 'pexpect.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 507
child_fd: 4
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: <open file 'actualjump.log', mode 'w' at 0xf230c0>
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

Code Sample (Not complete):

```
class Connection(object):
    # Login-handling 
        def login_to_domain(self, domain_ip, user, pwd):
        logger.debug('login_to_domain %s' % domain_ip)

    if self.ssh_tunnel == None:
        # for domain 1 let's start the connection
        cmd = 'ssh %s@%s' % (user, domain_ip)
        logger.debug('cmd: %s' % cmd)
        self.ssh_tunnel = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
    else:
        self.send_line('ssh %s@%s' % (user, domain_ip))
    if FULLLOG:  
        self.ssh_tunnel.logfile = file('actualjump.log','w')    

    for _ in range(5):
        logged_in = self.handle_domain_login(user, pwd)
        logger.debug('logged_in: %s' % logged_in)
        if logged_in == CONN_SUCCESS:
            return True
        if logged_in == CONN_FAIL:
            return False
    else:
        logger.warning('A problem logging in domain [%s]! Quitting.' % domain_ip)
        return False

    return False

def send(self,text):
    logger.debug('sending special line: %s' % text)
    print 'sending special line: %s' % text
    self.ssh_tunnel.send(text)
    #self.ssh_tunnel.expect(text)
    #self.ssh_tunnel.send('\n')
    self.ssh_tunnel.expect(['%'],60)
    resxx = self.ssh_tunnel.before + self.ssh_tunnel.after
    print "\nresxx:",resxx
c = Connection() # CALL CONNECTION CLASS
try:    
    D1_IP = domains.get('domains', '44')
    print "\nYOUR DOMAIN:\n",D1_IP,"\n"
except ConfigParser.NoOptionError:
    logger.error('Domain 1 or %s not specified in config file!', args.domain)
    raise IOSupgradeException('CMDS domain missing')

try:
    usernamex = cfgcred.get('domain login', 'username')
    passwordy = cfgcred.get('domain login', 'password')
except ConfigParser.NoOptionError:
    logger.error('login credentials not found in config file!')
    raise IOSupgradeException('login info missing')

try:
    tacacs_username = cfgcred.get('tacacs login', 'username')
    tacacs_password = cfgcred.get('tacacs login', 'password')
    print 'cmds %s/%s' % (tacacs_username, tacacs_password)
except ConfigParser.NoOptionError:
    logger.error('TACACS login credentials not found in config file!')
    raise IOSupgradeException('TACACS login info missing')

print 'connecting to jump server %s' % D1_IP
c.login_to_domain(D1_IP, usernamex, passwordy)

print 'Sending SNMP'
c.send('snmpwalk 10.1.1.1 snmpEngineTime')
```

Note: Not allowed to install any libraries like paramiko/netmiko which is more friendly so I have to create in a long method.

Please help or if you can share some sample script. thanks

Comment: How can you "not be allowed" to install paramiko? It's not like you need permission to write to `/usr` or whatever; you can put it anywhere you _do_ have permissions to write to, and adjust the PYTHONPATH appropriately.

Comment: ...anyhow, that's just an aside; the real problem with the question is its breadth -- as currently written, it's not asking about how to solve a specific pexpect problem you encountered, but how to make your whole program work.